# Problem while transferring data between POST request and GET in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I have a select tag, and what my logic is that after the user selects an option, we would send that response and search through the db to find similar records. The problem is how to access that data.
After the user has selected an option, I would take them to other page which is just a GET request page. So how to access the select tag data(which is a POST request data) on a GET request page.

Answer (score 0):

You can send selected data to server with POST and save data in **SESSION**
and Redirected to Next Page